# ASP.NET MVC 3.0 Razor Twitter helper slowing down pageload 

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am using `Twitter helper` from `Microsoft.Web.Helpers` http://twitterhelper.codeplex.com/

But it is a bit delaying page load, so i am wondering is it possible to load the scripts of that helper after page is ready?

For example `Twitter.Search("Hot Tweets")` produce this `scripts`:

**SCRIPTS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
new TWTR.Widget({
  version: 2,
  type: 'search',
  search: 'Hot Tweets',
  interval: 6000,
  title: '',
  subject: '',
  width: 250,
  height: 300,
  theme: {
    shell: {
      background: '#8ec1da',
      color: '#ffffff'
    },
    tweets: {
      background: '#ffffff',
      color: '#444444',
      links: '#1985b5'
    }
  },
  features: {
    scrollbar: false,
    loop: true,
    live: true,
    hashtags: true,
    timestamp: true,
    avatars: true,
    toptweets: true,
    behavior: 'default'
  }
}).render().start();
</script>
```

And than that scripts producing this html:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="twtr-widget twtr-paused" id="twtr-widget-1">
<div class="twtr-doc" style="width: 250px;">
<div class="twtr-hd">
<div class="twtr-bd">
<div class="twtr-ft">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

But it is not allowing to generate scripts separate so i would wrap them in to `$(document).ready()`

I can just split that code copy paste scripts and html separately....sounds a bit silly. So i am just wondering may be some one may suggest something more clever?

Answer (score 0):

Using `defer` `<script type='text/javascript' defer src=''></script>` will cause your scripts to be run after the document has been parsed and loaded.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js" defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript" defer>
    new TWTR.Widget({
        version: 2,
...
```

http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Deferred_Javascript

Comment: I think there is no way to say to that helper, to add defer in to <script>, only if i recompile that.

Comment: not sure what you mean bigb. noscript can't run any javascript so that wouldn't work.

Comment: @BuildStarted yes you right, what do you think what is better way to made such html modification on serverside?